# JAVA - Cambiar de color boton despues de cierto tiempo

Tags: java

estoy haciendo pruebas para un proyecto de mi escuela donde se me ocurrió la idea de hacer un sistema de renta de computadoras,  quiero hacer que si rento una computadora al finalizar el tiempo el botón correspondiente cambie pero poder agregar mas tiempo, por ejemplo, si rentan por 1 hora pero luego quieren agregar otra hora mas poder modificarlo directo desde la ejecución y no cerrar ni abrir de nuevo el programa. Vi que existe un programa llamado Ciber Control y me parecio que hace lo que busco, si alguien pudiera ayudarme me seria de mucha ayuda. GRACIAS!

Comment: Deberias poner el codigo que llevas hasta ahora par poder ayudarte y asesorarte, ya que las ideas al aire son dificiles de sostener

Comment: @srJJ hasta el momento solo lo tengo como idea y las pruebas solo las hice creando la interfaz, a lo que me refiero es poder ingresar el tiempo de renta y despues poder modificarlo mediante otro boton, despues de transcurrido este tiempo, el boton cambie de color

Comment: Hola @JOSEANGELSICAIROSELIZALDE, antes que nada tienes que poner el avance que tienes debido a que esta página es para ayudar con problemas que se tienen y para hacerte el trabajo, en cuanto a lo que dices es relativamente fácil hacerlo como dice la respuesta puedes utilizar Hilos, pero en el lugar donde tienes el tiempo puedes poner un evento que escuche los cambios hechos en ese campo, y que el evento modifique la variable de tiempo añadiendo el tiempo de duración de tu hilo o Timer que utilices.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que utilizar Thread(hilos) para hacer eso, tienes un hilo activo que va a ir preguntando si el tiempo se acabó depende del reloj de la máquina y el tiempo que le pongas para que cambie, si le da al boton de mas tiempo, llamas el mismo hilo para que inicie de nuevo.

Comment: Por ejemplo, guardar en un .txt la hora en la que el tiempo termina y con el Thread activo estara esperando que sea la hora indicada para cambiar el color?

Comment: Mas que en un txt en una variable y el bucle debe ser hasta que ese tiempo se termine

Comment: Para eso funciona handler

Comment: Un handler que el tiempo se establezca con una entreda del usuario, es decir en un edittext agreguen el tiempo presionen un boton que ejecutara el handler con el tiempo establecido en el edit